# How to handle exceptions in function-based context managers

Tags: python, contextmanager

In class based context managers you can handle and silence the expected exceptions in the **exit** method, and by returning true you can continue execution of the program.

```
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
    print("Leaving the context...")
    if isinstance(exc_value, IndexError):
        # Handle IndexError here...
        print(f"An exception occurred in your with block: {exc_type}")
        print(f"Exception message: {exc_value}")
        return True
```

I was wondering, is there a way of doing the same in function-based context managers? If yes, is that a good practice?

```
@contextmanager
def writable_file(file_path):
    file = open(file_path, mode="w")
    try:
        yield file
    finally:
        file.close()
```

Comment: So you are already using contextlib's contextmanager. What's the point of the question then?

Comment: @sudden_appearance the point is, how can you make sure that once exception raises, program doesn't stop execution? and what if I have a strategy of handling the exceptions? - taking default file or setting default parameter values.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to handle exceptions just handle them in try except block.

Do not forget to yield something when handling exceptions as it will raise

```
RuntimeException: generator didn't yield
```

Simple example of handling exception

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def divide(x, y):
    try:
        yield x / y

    except ZeroDivisionError as err:
        print("Zero division. Do not do that")
        yield None

    finally:
        ...
        # do some closing operations. DO NOT YIELD HERE!!!


with divide(5, 0) as result:
    print(result)
```